# Группировка истории изменения id в Oracle

Tags: oracle, group-by

имеется таблица с историей изменения некоторого id, в ней заданы 
1) дата начала действия id `START_DATE` 
2) дата окончание действия id `END_DATE`
3) `id`

```
with tmp (START_DATE, END_DATE, ID) as (
select TO_DATE('28.07.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), TO_DATE('01.01.2099', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 2 from dual union all
select TO_DATE('28.05.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), TO_DATE('28.07.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 1 from dual union all
select TO_DATE('19.02.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), TO_DATE('28.05.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 1 from dual union all
select TO_DATE('07.11.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), TO_DATE('19.02.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 1 from dual union all
select TO_DATE('31.08.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), TO_DATE('07.11.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 1 from dual union all
select TO_DATE('30.06.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), TO_DATE('31.08.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 1 from dual union all
select TO_DATE('30.09.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), TO_DATE('30.06.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 2 from dual union all
select TO_DATE('31.08.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), TO_DATE('30.09.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 1 from dual union all
select TO_DATE('31.07.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), TO_DATE('31.08.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 1 from dual union all
select TO_DATE('30.06.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), TO_DATE('31.07.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 2 from dual union all
select TO_DATE('31.05.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), TO_DATE('30.06.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 2 from dual
)
select * from tmp
```

Таблица для удобства уже отсортирована по убыванию `END_DATE`:

```
START_DATE  END_DATE    ID
----------  ----------  --
28.07.2018  01.01.2099  2
28.05.2018  28.07.2018  1
19.02.2018  28.05.2018  1
07.11.2017  19.02.2018  1
31.08.2017  07.11.2017  1
30.06.2017  31.08.2017  1
30.09.2016  30.06.2017  2
31.08.2016  30.09.2016  1
31.07.2016  31.08.2016  1
30.06.2016  31.07.2016  2
31.05.2016  30.06.2016  2
```

Необходимо сгруппировать таблицу так, чтобы одинаковые id непрерывные по датам от начала действия до окончания действия - **схлопнулись**. И получалась чередующая таблица изменения `id` следующего вида:

```
START_DATE  END_DATE    ID
----------  ----------  --
28.07.2018  01.01.2099  2
30.06.2017  28.07.2018  1
30.09.2016  30.06.2017  2
31.07.2016  30.09.2016  1
31.05.2016  31.07.2016  2
```

Заранее благодарю за проявленный интерес и любую помощь!

Comment: А с чем у вас проблемы? Как  пытались? Что не получается?

Comment: @Viktorov Проблема в том, что через группировку `min(START_DATE)` и `max(END_DATE)`  задача не решится. Другой способ который приходит на ум это через оконные функции, но не могу понять как это сделать

Comment: А каким образом получилась вторая запись (30.06.2017  28.07.2018  1) дата 30.06.2017 не является ни максимальной ни минимальной на том участке. c датой окончания то же самое

Comment: @Mike, вторая запись это соединение 6-й строки (**30.06.2017**  31.08.2017  1)  для `START_DATE` и 2-й строки (28.05.2018  **28.07.2018**  1)  для `END_DATE` все это по id = 1.

Comment: т.е. для start_date надо брать последнее значение окна, а для end_date первое ?

Comment: @Mike верно. Не могу сообразить как задать оконную функцию, так чтобы это условие выполнялось. При этом чтобы последнее значение по `START_DATE` не получилось последним среди всех записей в таблице, а первое по `END_DATE` соответственно первым среди всех записей в таблице

Answer (score 3):

Малость громоздко получилось, но более короткого пути пока не вижу:

```
select start_date, end_date, id
  from (
    select last_value(start_date) over(partition by grp order by end_date desc) start_date,
           first_value(end_date) over(partition by grp order by end_date desc) end_date,
           id, change, next
      from (
        select x.*, sum(change) over(order by end_date desc) grp
          from (
            select tmp.*, decode(id, lag(id) over(order by end_date desc), 0, 1) change,
                   decode(id, lead(id) over(order by end_date desc), 0, 1) next
              from tmp
          ) x
      )
  )
 where next=1
 order by end_date desc
```

Начиная с самого глубокого уровня вложенности: получаем флаг отличия записи от предыдущей (change) и от последующей (next). Формируем номер группы увеличивая его на 1 при каждом событии change (изменении id). Берем первое и последнее значения в каждой группе. Оставляем только записи next, в них актуальное значение start_date.

Answer (score 2):

Если версия БД 12c и выше, то можно решить эту задачу с клаузой `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`.

Рабочий пример:

```
select start_date, end_date, id 
from tmp
match_recognize (
    partition by id
    order by start_date
    measures 
        a.start_date as start_date,
        last (end_date) as end_date
    pattern (a b*)
    define b as start_date = prev (end_date)
)
order by end_date desc
```

Результат:

```
START_DATE END_DATE    ID
---------- ---------- ---
28.07.2018 01.01.2099   2
30.06.2017 28.07.2018   1
30.09.2016 30.06.2017   2
31.07.2016 30.09.2016   1
31.05.2016 31.07.2016   2
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня решение почти как у Mike, но немного короче:

```
with tmp (START_DATE, END_DATE, ID) as (
 ...
)
select to_char(min(start_date), 'dd.mm.yyyy') start_date, 
       to_char(max(end_date), 'dd.mm.yyyy') end_date, max(id)
  from (select start_date, end_date, id, 
               sum(group_id) over (order by end_date desc) group_id
          from (select start_date, end_date, id, 
                       case when lag(start_date) over (order by end_date desc) = end_date 
                             and lag(id) over (order by end_date desc) = id then 0 else rownum end group_id
                  from tmp
                )
        )
 group by group_id
 order by end_date desc
```

В самом внутреннем подзапросе в конструкции `case` я сравниваю `start_date` предыдущей строки и `end_date` текущей, а также `id` текущей и предыдущей. Если они совпадают, ставлю `0`, если нет - `rownum` (самый простой способ ввести уникальный идентификатор). Промежуточный результат выглядит так:

```
START_DATE  END_DATE            ID   GROUP_ID
----------- ----------- ---------- ----------
28/07/18    01/01/99             2          1
28/05/18    28/07/18             1          2
19/02/18    28/05/18             1          0
07/11/17    19/02/18             1          0
31/08/17    07/11/17             1          0
30/06/17    31/08/17             1          0
30/09/16    30/06/17             2          7
31/08/16    30/09/16             1          8
31/07/16    31/08/16             1          0
30/06/16    31/07/16             2         10
31/05/16    30/06/16             2          0
```

`group_id` - это как раз группы, которые определены в вопросе как "одинаковые id непрерывные по датам от начала действия до окончания действия". Числами обозначены начала каждой из групп. Дальше с помощью `sum(group_id) over (order by end_date desc)` заменяем нули в этом столбце номерами соответствующих групп, а дальше "задача сводится к предыдущей" - остается взять только `min(start_date)`/`max(end_date)` для каждой группы.